# Passing parameters within a sitemap

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameters, sitemap

How can get my SiteMapPath to work when i have dynamic URL's ?

For example i go from start.aspx to Country.aspx?countryID=1. I can only manage to get a link to Country.aspx but then the whole Point of my Navigation Fails becuase i don't know how to add the parameter...

I have a Hyperlinkfield that passes a new Parameter for each step in my Gridview. In start page it Looks like this.

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="CountryID" 
        DataTextField="CountryName" HeaderText="Countries" 
        DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Countries.aspx?countryID={0}" />
```

Example of sitemap

```
<siteMapNode url="~/Start.aspx" title="Start"  description="Start">
<siteMapNode url="~/Countries.aspx" title="Countries"  description="Countries">
  <siteMapNode url="~/States.aspx" title="States"  description="States">
    <siteMapNode url="~/Cities.aspx" title="Cities"  description="Cities">
    </siteMapNode>
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMapNode>
```

Maybe it's possible to make the sitemap to add the last exact URL from the last page to the SiteMapPath?

Comment: Take a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sitemap.sitemapresolve.aspx

Comment: That was to hard for me to understand, im a beginner. could you help me with some code?